# How can I render the emission only?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor

I'm currently struggling with something that's frustratating me now for a couple of hours and still im not getting a reasonable result.

I tracked a footage where I would like to insert a cube emitting light; there should be no shadow or Ambient Occlusion, at all. As you can see in the image bellow, currently the cube is casting a shadow; how can I fix that?

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

So actually i want to get rid off the shadow and Ambient Occlusion, which ofc isnt that much of an problem but in the mean time, i want to get the ermession of the cube (which is reflecting on the ground) to be rendered. I found out that there are render passes, which control the reflection on certain objects, but the wiki displays an "reflection" pass, which isnt obviously available in cycles. I tried out Ermession and enviroment passes though, without any success ._.

Comment: Welcome user14589 :) Please rephrase your question, it's hard to understand the issue... What exactly do you want to achieve? Also, start with the tour: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour to get your first badge ;)

Comment: It would help if show your complete node tree and not just a part of it... Seems like you are rendering what you need but are missing something on the compositor. Post your node tree and/or your blend file.